# Yarn: a way to prevent rebuilding native dependencies?

Tags: yarnpkg

I have joined a project where there are many native dependencies that need to be compiled. Most of them being crypto libraries.

The project also uses lerna and yarn workspaces. Every time I add or remove a package, yarn rebuilds all the native dependencies. It takes 10 minutes every time! Even if I just add a small package that should take 5 sec at worst.

I'd like to be able to prevent yarn from rebuilding everything all the time. Any solution?

I found this issue but it's closed. https://github.com/yarnpkg/yarn/issues/932